# Bash command that uses wildcard in place of folder to copy folder contents of multiple files into one directory?

Tags: bash, wildcards, command, file-copy

I have a directory `~/dir` that contains a bunch of random folders like: `~/dir/av 801` and `~/dir/lm 320`. I want to copy the contents of every inner folder (ie: av 801) into a different directory. The contents of that folder can consist of folders or files.

This is what I guessed the bash command would be:

```
cp ~/dir/*/* ~/target/
```

But it gives this error:

> cp: when copying multiple files, last argument must be a directory

Is there a bash command that can do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy directories, you need to tell `cp` to copy recursively by passing it the `-r` flag.

```
cp -R ~/dir/*/* ~/target/
```

If `~/target` does not exist, you need to create it first.

```
mkdir ~/target
```

Comment: that worked, except I was using eshell and I had to use a capital R for some reason: cp -R ~/dir/*/* ~target/

Comment: Apparently `-r` is [not portable](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75904/are-fifo-pipe-unix-domain-socket-the-same-thing-in-linux-kernel) while `-R` is.. I have modified my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Evan, did you mean to link to [-r is not portable](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18712/difference-between-cp-r-and-cp-r-copy-command/18718#18718)?

Comment: Yes. I pasted the wrong link.