# Are the named pipe created by `mknod` and the FIFO created by `mkfifo` equivalent?

Tags: fifo

I've used the `mkfifo <file>` command to create named FIFOs, where one process writes to the file, and another process reads from the file.

Now, I know the `mknod` command is able to create named pipes. Are these named pipes equivalent to the FIFOs created by `mkfifo`, or do they have different features?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it's equivalent, but obviously only if you tell `mknod` to actually create a FIFO, and not a block or character device (rarely done these days as devtmpfs/udev does it for you).

```
mkfifo foobar
# same difference
mknod foobar p
```

In `strace` it's identical for both commands:

```
mknod("foobar", S_IFIFO|0666)           = 0
```

So in terms of syscalls, `mkfifo` is actually shorthand for `mknod`.

The biggest difference, then, is in semantics. With `mkfifo` you can create a bunch of FIFOs in one go:

```
mkfifo a b c
```

With `mknod`, since you have to specify the type, it only ever accepts one argument:

```
# wrong:
$ mknod a b c p
mknod: invalid major device number ‘c’
# right:
mknod a p
mknod b p
mknod c p
```

In general, `mknod` can be difficult to use correctly. So if you want to work with FIFO, stick to `mkfifo`.

Comment: while the OP certainly doesn't care, since the Q is not tagged [linux], notice that on BSD `mkfifo(2)`  really is a separate system call from `mknod(2)` (but it'll end up doing exactly the same thing as `mknod(S_FIFO)`).

Comment: @frostschutz - thank you for an excellent answer. So just to clarify things. `mkfifo` and `mknod` are actually programs using the `mknod` system call (didn't knew of that system call before today) to create a FIFO. You use the terms "FIFO" and "named" interchangeably, I guess. Are they the same thing? Bi-directional named pipes are implemented by means of Unix domain sockets, right?

Comment: Yes, "named pipe" and FIFO usually refers to the same thing (in the context of pipes - [FIFO is a concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_%28computing_and_electronics%29) that exists outside of pipes as well). A socket is a different beast altogether, some interesting answers to that here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75904/30851

Comment: @frostschutz - thank you. I guess what confused me most is that, when I think of named pipes, I also think of bi-directional pipes - and a FIFO is definitely not bi-directional (AFAIK).

Comment: @Shuzheng a FIFO does not have any rules on direction really. It's really just read and write. There can be any number of readers and writers, but anything written can only be read once, so it's unclear who would get the data in the end.

Answer (score 19):

They are equivalent except at the extreme edges of portability. `mknod ... p` was originally the only way to create named pipes, but POSIX chose to omit it and invent `mkfifo` instead, presumably because named pipes are an inherently more portable concept than all that other stuff `mknod` can do with devices and their major and minor numbers. The `mknod` system call was also left out of the early verions of POSIX.

So, for portability to ancient UNIX, `mknod ... p` is better. For modern systems, `mkfifo` is slightly better, although it's pretty unlikely that you'll find an actual modern unix where `mknod ... p` doesn't work.